# Response Entity not getting mapped for custom objects inside a class

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot

I am hitting an API and getting the response using resttemplate.exchange object and i am mapping the response to a parameterized object .All the variables inside the response class are getting mapped to the response entity object but not the Attribute class variables inside the parameterized object.

```
  ResponseEntity<ArrayList<Response>> responseEntity = 
restTemplate.exchange(
            builder.toUriString(), 
            HttpMethod.GET, 
            new HttpEntity<>(headers), 
            new ParameterizedTypeReference<ArrayList<Response>>() 
{});


@Getter
@Setter
public class Response {
private String number;
private String id;
private String name;


@JsonProperty("attributes")
private ArrayList<Attributes> attributes ;

}


@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class Attributes {


private String value;
private String name;
}
```

Comment: What error message is displayed?

Comment: No error, when i debug and check the responseentity could see the com.util.Response@18d34 in place of response

Comment: Okay. Did you try to add getters and setters for attributes manually?

Comment: I added a toString Method in the Response class which resolved the issue.